# Checking the checkBox does not work when DataTable of react-data-table-component has a onSelectedRowsChange callback withs state change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following code, where I want to enable the edit button when a row is checked.
So I have set **editButtonDisabled** as a state variable to handle the disable attribute of the button.

Now the problem is when I check the unchecked checkBox of the row, the edit button gets enabled, but the uncheck checkbox remains unchecked. If I check it again, then it becomes checked. When I uncheck it, it becomes unchecked with the button being disabled.

If I remove the callback, it works fine. So I am guessing that the changing the state of the variable is messing with my checkbox. What can be done to resolve this problem?

```
import { useEffect, useState, useRef, useCallback } from 'react';
import { getDocs, query, collection, orderBy, doc } from 'firebase/firestore';
import DataTable from 'react-data-table-component';
import { Button, Checkbox } from '@mui/material';
import { FcInspection } from 'react-icons/fc';
import { IoAdd } from 'react-icons/io5';
import { VscEdit } from 'react-icons/vsc';
import { db } from '../../../services/firebase';
import { Layout } from '../../layout';

export default function InstituteList() {
  const [retrievedFlag, setRetrievedFlag] = useState(false);
  const [institutes, setInstitutes] = useState([]);
  const [editButtonDisabled, setEditButtonDisabled] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (retrievedFlag === false) retrieveData();
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(editButtonDisabled);
  }, [editButtonDisabled])

  function retrieveData() {
    try {
      let tmpInstitutes = [];
      const institutesRef = collection(db, 'Institutes');
      const institutesQuery = query(institutesRef, orderBy('title'));
      getDocs(institutesQuery)
      .then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          let institute = doc.data();
          institute.id = doc.id;
          tmpInstitutes.push(institute);
        });
        setInstitutes(tmpInstitutes);
        setRetrievedFlag(true);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  const columns = [
    { name: 'id', selector: row => row.id, omit: true },
    { name: '조직명', selector: row => row.title, sortable: true, grow: 1 },
    { name: '등록일', selector: row => row.date, sortable: true, grow: 1 },
    { name: '주소', selector: row => row.location, sortable: true, grow: 4 },
  ];

  const handleSelectedRowChange = useCallback((state) => {
    console.log('Set edit button disable state', state);
    setEditButtonDisabled(state.selectedCount == 0);
  });

  const paginationComponentOptions = {
    rowsPerPageText: '페이지당 조회 갯수',
    rangeSeparatorText: '중',
    selectAllRowsItem: true,
    selectAllRowsItemText: '전체',
  }

  const PageHeader = (userInfo) => {
    const today = new Date();
    return (
      <div className="page-header">
        <div className="page-header__title">
          <FcInspection />
          조직목록조회
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

  const DataTableHeader = () => {
    return (
      <div className="page-body__datatable_header">
        <div className="page-body__datatable_header__title">조직목록</div>
        <div className="page-body__datatable_header__title"></div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  const PageDataTable = () => {
    return (
      <div className="page-body__card_datatable">
        <DataTable
          title='조직목록'
          noDataComponent='조회 할 데이터 없습니다.'
          columns={columns}
          data={institutes}
          persistTableHead={true}
          noContextMenu={true}
          selectableRows={true}
          selectableRowsHighlight={true}
          selectableRowsComponent={Checkbox}
          selectableRowsSingle={true}
          onSelectedRowsChange={handleSelectedRowChange}
          pagination
          paginationComponentOptions={paginationComponentOptions}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }

  const PageDataTableButtons = () => {
    console.log("Render PageDataTableButtons");
    return (
      <div className="page-body__card_buttons">
        <Button variant="contained" id="datatable_button_add" startIcon={<IoAdd />}>추가</Button>
        <Button variant="contained" id="datatable_button_modify" startIcon={<VscEdit />} disabled={editButtonDisabled}>수정</Button>
      </div>
    )
  }

  const PageBody = () => {
    return (
      <div className="page-body">
        <div className="page-body__card">
          <PageDataTable />
          <PageDataTableButtons />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <Layout>
      {userInfo => (
        <main className="main">
          <PageHeader />
          <PageBody />
        </main>
      )}
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that **useEffect** is causing the problem.

I have created a separate component file for **datatable** related components, and the problem was resolved.

But I would still love to know why it was causing the problem.